# SQL Distinct join with SUM

Tags: sql, t-sql

im facing a little issue with sql join

I have 2 tables

```
*1st table*                  *2nd table*
Reference   Name             Reference   Amount
123         Test1            123         52
145         Test2            232         22
123         Test3            123         33
555         Test4            145         44
123         Test5            656         55
```

I need something like

```
select distinct(a.reference), sum(b.amount) from 1st a left join 2nd b ON a.Reference = b.Reference group by a.reference
```

this look pretty simple for me, but what it does - it gives me SUM multiple times where reference is 123 so it will give me (52+33)*3

what should I use to get unique SUM's per Reference?

Thx!

edit:

final result should look like

```
123   85
145   44
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the results that you are looking for.  You don't explain what you want anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the `distinct` before the `join`:

```
select a.reference, sum(b.amount)
from (select distinct reference from a) a left join 
     b 
     a.Reference = b.Reference
group by a.reference;
```

You almost never need to use `select distinct` with `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is incorrect,

you should not use distinct since we have group by..

So your should be likely,

```
select a.reference, sum(b.amount) from 1st a 
 left join 2nd b ON a.Reference = b.Reference group by a.reference
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a CTE to resolve your issue:

```
WITH cte
AS
(

SELECT DISTINCT reference FROM 1st 

)

SELECT a.reference, SUM(b.amount)
FROM cte a
LEFT JOIN 2nd b ON a.Reference = b.Reference
GROUP BY a.reference
```